# Apply date filter multiple times

Tags: javascript, json, wcf, date, angularjs

In my angular application I'm calling a WCF REST service, which returns an array ob objects, where one of the property is of type DateTime, which gets serialized in JSON in such a form

`[{"date":"\/Date(1295164800000-0800)\/",...`

to display it nicely in my template I created a filter to convert that JSON representation into JavaScript Date object.

```
eventsApp.filter("fromMSDate", function(){
   return function (jsonDate) {
       var D, dtime, T, tz, off,
           dobj = jsonDate.match(/(\d+)|([+-])|(\d{4})/g);
       T = parseInt(dobj[0]);
       tz = dobj[1];
       off = dobj[2];
       if (off) {
           off = (parseInt(off.substring(0, 2), 10) * 3600000) +
               (parseInt(off.substring(2), 10) * 60000);
           if (tz == '-') off *= -1;
       }
       else off = 0;
       return new Date(T + off).toUTCString();
   }
});
```

I'm using it this way

```
            <span class="span1">Date:</span>
            <span>{{event.date | fromMSDate}}</span>
```

All works as needed, I do have a JS Date object shown in the page, but I don't like the format, so I tried to apply the `'date'` filter but it had no success.

```
            <span class="span1">Date:</span>
            <span>{{event.date | fromMSDate | date:'medium'}}</span>
```

the `date` filter is ignored for some reason and the date is shown as `Fri, 15 Mar 2013 00:00:00 GMT`.

What am I doing wrong here?

Thx

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`Date.prototype.toUTCString` returns date in a format ("Mon, 03 Jul 2006 21:44:38 GMT") which is not recognised by Angular's date filter.

[From date filter docs](http://code.angularjs.org/1.1.5/docs/api/ng.filter%3adate):

> [Param `date`:] Date to format either as Date object, milliseconds
>   (string or number) or various ISO 8601 datetime string formats (e.g.
>   yyyy-MM-ddTHH:mm:ss.SSSZ and its shorter versions like
>   yyyy-MM-ddTHH:mmZ, yyyy-MM-dd or yyyyMMddTHHmmssZ). If no timezone is
>   specified in the string input, the time is considered to be in the
>   local timezone.

So, to produce a format that date filter can understand use `Date.prototype.toISOString` which produces date in date filter compatible format ("2013-10-31T08:36:14.601Z").

```js
app.controller('AppCtrl', function($scope){
  $scope.jsonDate = "\/Date(1295164800000-0800)\/";
});

app.filter("fromMSDate", function(){
 return function (jsonDate) {
   var D, dtime, T, tz, off,
   dobj = jsonDate.match(/(\d+)|([+-])|(\d{4})/g);
   T = parseInt(dobj[0]);
   tz = dobj[1];
   off = dobj[2];
   if (off) {
     off = (parseInt(off.substring(0, 2), 10) * 3600000) +
           (parseInt(off.substring(2), 10) * 60000);
     if (tz == '-') off *= -1;
   }
   else off = 0;
   return new Date(T + off).toISOString();
 }
});
```

```html
<div ng-controller="AppCtrl">

  <div>date json: {{jsonDate}}</div> <!-- == /Date(1295164800000-0800)/ -->
  <div>date fromMSDate: {{jsonDate | fromMSDate}}</div> <!-- == 2011-01-16T00:00:00.000Z -->
  <div>date medium: {{jsonDate | fromMSDate | date:'medium'}}</div> <!-- == Jan 16, 2011 1:00:00 AM -->
  <div>date short: {{jsonDate | fromMSDate | date:'short'}}</div> <!-- == 1/16/11 1:00 AM -->

</div>
```

Comment: Thank you. Working as expected